# Remove text after second colon

Tags: r, regex, regex-group

I need to remove everything after the second colon. I have several date formats, that need to be cleaned using the same algorithm.

```
a <- "2016-12-31T18:31:34Z"
b <- "2016-12-31T18:31Z"
```

I have tried to match on the two column groups, but I cannot seem to find out how to remove the second match group.

```
sub("(:.*){2}", "", "2016-12-31T18:31:34Z")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A regex you can use: `(:[^:]+):.*`

which you can check on: [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/iv3W3P/1) and use like

```
sub("(:[^:]+):.*", "\\1", "2016-12-31T18:31:34Z")
[1] "2016-12-31T18:31"
sub("(:[^:]+):.*", "\\1", "2016-12-31T18:31Z")
[1] "2016-12-31T18:31Z"
```

Answer (score 1):

Let say you have a vector:

```
date <- c("2016-12-31T18:31:34Z", "2016-12-31T18:31Z", "2017-12-31T18:31Z")
```

Then you could split it by ":" and take only first two elements dropping the rest:

```
out = sapply(date, function(x) paste(strsplit(x, ":")[[1]][1:2], collapse = ':'))
```

Comment: Thanks, I was considering this option, but wanted the code to be more clean with a regex.

Answer (score 0):

Use it as an opportunity to make a partial timestamp validator vs just targeting any trailing seconds:

```
remove_seconds <- function(x) {
  require(stringi)
  x <- stri_trim_both(x)
  x <- stri_match_all_regex(x, "([[:digit:]]{4}-[[:digit:]]{2}-[[:digit:]]{2}T[[:digit:]]{2}:[[:digit:]]{2})")[[1]]
  if (any(is.na(x))) return(NA)  
  sprintf("%sZ", x[,2])
}
```

That way, you'll catch errant timestamp strings.