# Remove string after second colon in Java

Tags: java, android

I would like to remove the string after the second colon and add a new string behind.

I have a maker when clicking on a marker I add the string using ALertDialog on the marker title so I can get those value to the process for a text file. But if I select that marker again I want to remove that text after colon so I don't add duplicate string again.

[image]

I checked this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46213661/remove-text-after-second-colon) but it uses a regular expression and I don't have any experience with that.

> My String = W:3:ER1,ER2,ER3,,,,

> Output = W:3

I would like to remove the string after the second colon so I can attach my string

Here is my **onMarkerClick**

```
      @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {
        final String[] title = {marker.getTitle()};
        Bitmap smallDot = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(getBitmapFromVectorDrawable(getApplicationContext(),
                R.drawable.blue_dot), 15, 15, false);

        final String[] selectedItems = {"", "", "", "", ""};

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle("Enable Relays");

        // add a checkbox list
        final String[] relays = {"Relay 1", "Relay 2", "Relay 3", "Relay 4", "Implement"};
        boolean[] checkedItems = {true, false, false, true, false};


        builder.setMultiChoiceItems(relays, null, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {

                if (isChecked) {
                    // If the user checked the item, add it to the selected items
                    selectedItems[which] = "ER" + (which + 1);
                } else if (!isChecked) {
                    // Else, if the item is already in the array, remove it
                    selectedItems[which] = "";
                }
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + Arrays.toString(selectedItems), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }).setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

//                title[0] +=  ":" + selectedItems[0] + "," + selectedItems[1] + "," + selectedItems[2] + "," + selectedItems[3] + "," + selectedItems[4];

                int commas = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < title[0].length(); i++) {
                    if (title[0].charAt(i) == ',') commas++;
                }
                if (!title[0].contains("ER1") && commas <= 4)
                    title[0] += ":" + selectedItems[0];
                if (!title[0].contains("ER2") && commas <= 4)
                    title[0] += "," + selectedItems[1];
                if (!title[0].contains("ER3") && commas <= 4)
                    title[0] += "," + selectedItems[2];
                if (!title[0].contains("ER4") && commas <= 4)
                    title[0] += "," + selectedItems[3];
                if (!title[0].contains("ER5") && commas <= 4)
                    title[0] += "," + selectedItems[4];

                marker.setTitle(title[0]);
                marker.showInfoWindow();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + title[0], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }).setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            }
        });

        // create and show the alert dialog
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();

        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the trick to remove string after the second colon.

First, find the position for the second colon. Then remove the string after that position.

Here the method for finding the position

```
private static int findSecondColonPosition(String s) {
        int result = -1;
        int dotsToFind = 2;
        char[] ca = s.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < ca.length; ++i) {
            if (ca[i] == ':') --colonsToFind;
            if (dotsToFind == 0) return i;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Here my updated **onMarkerClick** code

```
    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {
        final String[] title = {marker.getTitle()};
        Bitmap smallDot = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(getBitmapFromVectorDrawable(getApplicationContext(),
                R.drawable.blue_dot), 15, 15, false);

        final String[] selectedItems = { "", "", "", ""};

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle("Enable Relays");

        // add a checkbox list
        final String[] relays = {"Relay 2", "Relay 3", "Relay 4", "Implement"};

        builder.setMultiChoiceItems(relays, null, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {

                if (isChecked) {
                    // If the user checked the item, add it to the selected items
                    selectedItems[which] = "ER" + (which + 2);
                } else if (!isChecked) {
                    // Else, if the item is already in the array, remove it
                    selectedItems[which] = "";
                }
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + Arrays.toString(selectedItems), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }).setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                int secoundColonPosition = findSecondColonPosition(title[0]);

                if (secoundColonPosition > 0) {
                    System.out.println("title after remove: " + title[0].substring(0, secoundColonPosition));
                    title[0] = title[0].substring(0, secoundColonPosition);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("ERROR: there is not a 2nd colon in " + title[0]);
                }

                title[0] += ":" + selectedItems[0] + "," + selectedItems[1] + "," + selectedItems[2] + "," + selectedItems[3];

                marker.setTitle(title[0]);
                marker.showInfoWindow();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + title[0], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }).setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            }
        });

        // create and show the alert dialog
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();

//        if (isEnable()) {
//            title += ":Enable_Implement";
//            marker.setTitle(title);
//            marker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallDot));
//            setEnable(false);
//            setDisable(true);
//            programStatusTextView.setText("Choose a stop actuation point");
//        } else if (isDisable()) {
//            title += ":Disable_Implement";
//            marker.setTitle(title);
//            marker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallDot));
//            setDisable(false);
//            programStatusTextView.setText("");
//        }

        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First we split on the last `:` to get the title.
Then we parse on `,` from the last `:` to get items and we filter out empty ones.

```java
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String raw = "W:3:ER1,ER2,ER3,,,,";
        String title = raw.substring(0, raw.lastIndexOf(":"));
        String[] selectedItems = raw.substring(raw.lastIndexOf(":")+1).split(",");
        List<String> items = Arrays.asList(selectedItems).stream().filter(str ->
            ! "".equals(str)
        ).collect(Collectors.toList());


        System.out.println("Title "+ title);
        System.out.println("Items "+ items);
    }
}
```

Prints

> Title W:3
> Items [ER1, ER2, ER3]

***Edit 1** : Should handle single colon*

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String raw = "W:3";
        List<String> items;
        String title;
        if (raw.replaceAll("[^:]", "").length() > 1) { // String with every :
            title = raw.substring(0, raw.lastIndexOf(":"));
            String[] selectedItems = raw.substring(raw.lastIndexOf(":") + 1).split(",");
            items = Arrays.asList(selectedItems).stream().filter(str ->
                    !"".equals(str)
            ).collect(Collectors.toList());
        } else {
            title = raw;
            items = null;
        }


        System.out.println("Title "+ title);
        System.out.println("Items "+ items);
    }
}
```

And prints for `raw = "W:3";`

> Title W:3
> Items null

Comment: What if there is String raw = W:3? What does it do?

Comment: What should it do ?
You do not give any specifications about how `raw` string might be generated

Comment: @ArpitPatel title = "W" and Items = ["3"] but a simple check on occurence of `":"` will do the trick

Comment: @ArpitPatel uplaoded an edited version that checks occurences of `":"` before doing the job

Comment: Thank You for edit I don't understand this line of code raw.replaceAll("[^:]", "")

Comment: @ArpitPatel it does replace `^` (everything but) `:` by `""` which returns a String with only `:`.
Using `.length()` allows you to count amount of `":"` in `raw` and adapt behavior